# Xamarin Forms having trouble centering a collectionview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a collection view like so:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding subCategories}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalGrid, 3" IsVisible="{Binding isCollection}" HeightRequest="250" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout Spacing="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="20" Margin="20" Padding="20">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="#02cc9d" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                </Frame>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CollectionView>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

There are 2 things I am trying to do here, the first is center this collection view, I have tried all the HorizontalOptions on the StackLayout and on the CollectionView. The other thing that I bothering me is when an item is selected, the grey box that appears to indicate an item is selected is also not centered, how do I fix this collection view to make it look nicer?

Comment: A `HorizontalGrid` layout is one that **grows horizontally** as needed. It may be difficult to center horizontally, because it is prepared to grow horizontally if you add more items. Try `ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3"`. With different layout options.

Comment: Re the selection box. What is the purpose of `StackLayout` inside the itemtemplate? (It can't fix any problem at the list level, because it is describing what happens in each item.) If you remove that wrapper, have Frame directly inside datatemplate, does the grey selection box look different?

Comment: The purpose of the StackLayout is to add spacing

Comment: `ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3"` actually fixed both problems

Answer (score 0):

A `HorizontalGrid layout` is one that **grows horizontally** as needed. It may be difficult to center horizontally, because it is prepared to grow horizontally if you add more items.

Try `ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3"`.

If necessary, test with different layout options.

(OP says in comment that this fixed both problems.)